# PHP blocking access to the login page after three unsuccessful login attempts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i want to block user for certain time after 3 wrong login attempts using ip.
my problem is that the counter is always 1 every time i enter wrong data the counter is still 1
any help where i am wrong in the below code?!

Table name attempts 
cols when,ip

```
<?php
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=e-check";
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "";
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$max_time_in_seconds = 5;
$max_attempts = 3;
//here i printed to see ht counter number
echo login_attempt_count($max_time_in_seconds, $pdo) <= $max_attempts;
 if(login_attempt_count($max_time_in_seconds, $pdo) <= $max_attempts){
    // login form
    echo'      
<form action="index_new.php" method="POST">
        <table align="left">
            <tr><td><span class="caption">login form</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>
            <tr><td>name:</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="uname" required></td> </tr>
            <tr><td>pass:</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="password" name="psswd" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="button1"><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="login" class="button"></td></tr>
        </table> </form>';

} else {
    echo "<div class='test'>will be blocked for few seconds</div>";
}function login_attempt_count($seconds, $pdo) {
    try {
        // delete old attempts from the table
        $del_old = "DELETE FROM attempts WHERE `when` < ?";
        $oldest = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$seconds." seconds");
        $oldest = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$oldest);
        $del_data = array($oldest);
        $remove = $pdo->prepare($del_old);
        $remove->execute($del_data);
        // insert this attempt into the table
        $insert = "INSERT INTO attempts (`ip`, `when`) VALUES ( ?, ? )";
        $data = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $input = $pdo->prepare($insert);
        $input->execute($data);
        //count the number of recent attempts from this ip address  
        $count = "SELECT count(*) as number FROM attempts where `ip` = ?";
        $num = $pdo->prepare($count);
        $num->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
        foreach($num as $attempt) {
            $attempts = $attempt['number'];
        }return $attempts;
    } catch (PDOEXCEPTION $e) {
        echo "Error: ".$e;}}?>
```

Comment: Increase $max_time_in_seconds up to 60 and check again.

Comment: `WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 60 SECOND)` maybe?

Comment: You want to UPDATE the row on failed attempts, not INSERT. That's why you always have the 1 count. You're always inserting the same one.

Comment: Also just use `NOW()` or `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` when inserting to be sure that the times are identical to what the database thinks "now" is. Without a working `ntpd` your servers can and will drift, so be careful.

Comment: This logic is simple: `if(login is not successful) { UPDATE a row adding 1 to attempts row for the user } else{ it's successful, do something }` and keep adding to the row if failed then count the number of tries, `if (attempts >=3)` etc. That's what I would do.

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov i would get the message from the first wrong login.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the concept is clear its just converting that to code is confusing, do i Update instead of Insert is that what you mean?

Comment: That is exactly what I meant and said ;-) You're INSERTing what seems to me, being the same thing each time. The INSERT will never equal 3 for a given row because each row containing the IPs or same IP's, all contain "1", not "2", or "3", but "1", and that's why you have "1" for a count each time. That's what I make of it. Like I said, you want to UPDATE on failed attempts with a WHERE clause.

Comment: On SELECT, you'd query/count a said INT row (boolean) and use a `while` loop and inside it, check `if($row['attempts'] >=1){ safe so far }` - `if($row['attempts'] >=2){ safe so far }` - `if($row['attempts'] >=3){ NOT OK }` type of thing. A case switch would also be easier

Comment: ping me back, I haven't heard anything back from my last 2 comments. good luck

Comment: i am sorry am trying but i could get it done right!! @Fred-ii-

Comment: Start/test with a clean table with 2-3 different rows. Use the basics I've given you and then slowly start adding in the rest of your code that you're using now. You'll see, you'll get it going ;-) *I'm sure of it.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122244/discussion-between-suma-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=e-check";
$username = "root"; 
$password = "";
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$max_time_in_seconds = 5;
$max_attempts = 3;
//here i printed to see ht counter number
echo login_attempt_count($max_time_in_seconds, $pdo) <= $max_attempts;
if(login_attempt_count($max_time_in_seconds, $pdo) <= $max_attempts){
// login form
echo'      
<form action="index_new.php" method="POST">
    <table align="left">
        <tr><td><span class="caption">login form</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>
        <tr><td>name:</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="uname" required></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>pass:</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="password" name="psswd" required></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="button1"><input type="submit" name="submitBtn"         value="login" class="button"></td></tr>
    </table> </form>';

} else {
echo "<div class='test'>will be blocked for few seconds</div>";
}function login_attempt_count($seconds, $pdo) {
try {
    //do not delete old attempts from the table

    // insert this attempt into the table
    $insert = "INSERT INTO attempts (`ip`, `when`) VALUES ( ?, ? )";
    $data = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    $input = $pdo->prepare($insert);
    $input->execute($data);
    //count the number of recent attempts from this ip address  
    $count = "SELECT count(*) as number FROM attempts where (when > now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) and `ip` = ?";
    $num = $pdo->prepare($count);
    $num->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    foreach($num as $attempt) {
        $attempts = $attempt['number'];
    }return $attempts;
} catch (PDOEXCEPTION $e) {
    echo "Error: ".$e;}}?>
```

Also, you will want to run a cron job of some sort to clear out the table of old logins. On my own server I have it clear out login data that is over a month old. It runs every night at midnight. If you are only storing failed logins you can clear out all rows older then X minutes every night.